# add rounded corners to GoogleMaps info Window

Tags: android, android-layout, google-maps-api-3

This is the xml file I use to style my Info Window:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map_info_window"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_grey"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am not sure how to make it with round corners.